# Bash paste -d " " command outputting a return separated file

Tags: bash, paste

I am trying to combine two text files each with a single column into a third text file that has both of the columns separated by a space.

One text file looks something like the following (shortened for the purpose of this explanation):

```
-53.46
-50.45
-47.44
```

The second text file looks something like this (also shortened for this explanation):

```
1.71
3.42
5.13
```

and I want to combine them to get a file:

```
-53.46 1.71
-50.45 3.42
-47.44 5.13
```

Currently I am trying the method:

```
paste -d " " file1 file2 > file3
```

but then when I view the file with the less command the columns are separated by

```
^M
```

And if I view them in gedit or similar they are each on a different line with a space at the start of each line.

Please send help.

Comment: was your file1 generated in windows system? if it is true, you may want to convert it  into unix format, e.g the linebreaks. some tools can help you, e.g. sed, vim or dos2unix etc.

Comment: Nope both were created on linux. I created file2 myself while file1 was outputted by a unix program. Perhaps I should double check the formatting of file1.

Comment: works for me

`paste -d " " values1 values2 > out` , no ^M separates columns

Comment: I just double checked file1 and it has a space at the start of each row but I assume this shouldn't matter.