# Reading two columns in two files and outputting them to another file

Tags: bash, awk

I recently posted this question - [`paste -d " "` command outputting a return separated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150503/bash-paste-d-command-outputting-a-return-separated-file)

However I am concerned there is formatting in the text files that is causing it to error. For this reason I am attempting to do it with `awk`.

I am not very experienced with `awk` but currently I have the following:

```
 awk {print $1} file1 | {print $1} file2 > file 3
```

Is this the kind of syntax I should be using? It gives an error saying missing `}` Each file contains a single column of numbers and the same number of rows.

Comment: Please do not post links which have another data, post all details with in same post itself, kindly post sample of input and sample of output too in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing your OLD post seems to be you could have control M characters in your files. To remove control M characters in your files either use `dos2unix` utility or use following command(s).

1st: To remove junk chars everywhere.

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

2nd: To remove them only at last of lines use following.

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

I believe once you remove junk chars your `paste` command should work properly too. Run following after you fix the control M chars in your Input_file(s).

```
paste -d " " Input_file1  Input_file2 > Output_file
```

OR to concatenate 2 files simply use:(considering that your Input_files have either 1 column or you want full lines to be there in output)

```
cat Input_file1 Input_file2 > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1;next}{print a[FNR],$1}' a.txt b.txt > output.txt
```

**a.txt:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**b.txt:**

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

**output.txt:**

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```